# Dependency injection error with mass transit and rabbitmq Ipublishendpoint in .net 6

Tags: dependency-injection, rabbitmq, .net-6.0, masstransit

I Have two files:

Program.cs:

```
serviceSettings = configuration.GetSection(nameof(ServiceSettings)).Get<ServiceSettings>();
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
    {
        var rabbitMQSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(RabbitMQSettings)).Get<RabbitMQSettings>();
        configurator.Host(rabbitMQSettings.Host);
        configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter(serviceSettings.ServiceName, false));
    });
});


services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());

services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
```

and ItemsController.cs which is my controller-

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("items")]
    public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Item> itemRepository;
        private readonly IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint;
        private static int requestCounter = 0;

        public ItemsController(IRepository<Item> itemRepository, IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint)
        {
            this.publishEndpoint = publishEndpoint;
            this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ItemDto>> CreateItemAsync(CreateItemDto createItemDto)
        {
            var item = new Item
            {
                Name = createItemDto.Name,
                Description = createItemDto.Description,
                Price = createItemDto.Price,
                CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
            };
            await itemRepository.CreateItemAsync(item);

            await publishEndpoint.Publish(new CatalogItemCreated(item.Id, item.Name, item.Description));

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(CreateItemAsync), new { id = item.Id }, item);

        }
```

But everytime I hit the route- https://localhost:7234/items which used to previously work(before setup of rabbitmq) is giving me this error-

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MassTransit.IPublishEndpoint' while attempting to activate 'Play.Catalog.Service.Controllers.ItemsController'.
```

The App builds and run just fine but gives this error whenever I try any endpoints.
I also tried to change versions to 7.1.3 for MassTransit.RabbitMQ but to no avail.

Comment: MassTransit is currently on v8.1, I'd suggest if you're starting out, you start there.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I see that you are working with Julio Casal's codebase. In that course he recommends using version 7.3.1, not the 7.1.3 that you are using. Also, Julio has a community for users of his material, you could ask there. Did you try?